# program to show if the value is alphabet then print "Alphabet" if it’s a number then print "Digit" and for other characters print "Special Character"?

Tags: java, if-statement, control-flow

I have completed the program but in case of negative numbers it shows special character but I don't want that I want it should display number.

```
public class DigitAlphabetSpecialCharacter {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    char char1 =scanner.next().charAt(0);
    if(char1>=48 && char1<=57)
    {
        System.out.print("char is Digit");

    }
    else if((char1>='a' && char1<='z')||(char1>='A' && char1<='Z'))
    {
        System.out.print("char is Alphabet");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("char is special character");

    }
}
```

}
can anyone tell how to use negative numbers'ASCII value or an alternative suggestion?

Comment: A negative number is made of at least 2 characters. You only check the first one, and minus symbol is a special character according to your code

Comment: Well, from what you just wrote, you are taking the first character. So obviously, in the case of a negative digit, the first char is `-`, hence a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, if you enter `-9`, your code will only take `-`. You can simply check for the negative sign

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        char char1 =scanner.next().charAt(0);
        if((char1>=48 && char1<=57) || char1 == 45)
        {
            System.out.print("char is Digit");

        }
        else if((char1>='a' && char1<='z')||(char1>='A' && char1<='Z'))
        {
            System.out.print("char is Alphabet");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("char is special character");

        }
    }
```

Comment: what if input is just `-`?

Comment: @jhamon, As OP is taking only first character from the input, we cannot find out if it is just `-` or `-9`. He need to change the logic while taking input.

Answer (score 2):

Character cannot hold a negative value as it requires two characters. And a char variable can store only single character.

And rather than using ASCII value, you can use function predefined in **Character** class.

Answer (score 1):

try like this using regex

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
      String char1 = String.valueOf(scanner.next().charAt(0));

      if(char1.matches("[0-9]") || char1.matches("-[0-9]"))
      {
        System.out.print("char is Digit");

      }
      else if(char1.matches("[a-zA-Z]"))
      {
        System.out.print("char is Alphabet");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print("char is special character");

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Scanner object, why not make use of its functionality.

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int value = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print(value + " is a number");
    return;
}

String value = scanner.next();

if (value.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
char c = value.charAt(0);

if ((c>='a' && c <= 'z') || (c>='A' && c <= 'Z')) {
    System.out.print("char is Alphabet");
} else {
    System.out.print("char is special character");
}
scanner.close();
```